# Java - Retrieving data from servlet method and display on JSP

Tags: java, ajax, json, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page where I display my customers names, and I need to be able to display any customer full data upon clicking on the customer name, so I made a small Ajax call to render a customer object from the DB so that I can display it in my JSP page. But I am always getting error code 500 (internal server error), so can someone please tell me:
1. What exactly I am doing wrong here? and how to fix it?
2. Is there any better approach than that I am trying?

Thanks

```
    function loadSingleCustomerdata(customerid){        

               var customerData="?customerID="+customerid;
       alert(customerData);

            $.ajax({                    
                url: "LoadSingleCustomerData"+customerData,
                success: function(customerDataRec){
                    alert(customerDataRec.firstName);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "admin/customers/LoadSingleCustomerData")
public @ResponseBody
Customer getSingleCustomerData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception {

    Long id= Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("customerID"));
    Customer customer=icustomerservice.getCustomerByPK(id);
    return customer;        
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the stacktrace for '500 (internal server error)',so that it would be easy to resolve the error. Stacktrace can be obtained from catalina.out file for tomcat

or directly from browse. 1.Press Ctrl+Shift+J on chrome 2.Go to network 3.Execute the AJAX URL. 4.You'll get the error in preview.

Comment: I am not sure where to get the stack trace from Chrome dev tools, I have the network tab on, what's in header, preview response don't reveal much info, so can you be more precise what info you exactly need from the network tab?